# Batch subroutine in for loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, copy, call

Any ideas why this wouldn't work ? I have tried to replace `%A%` with `%%f` in the subroutine, but it wouldn't work anyways.

```
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%f in (*.bat) do (set A=%%f call :subroutine %%f)

    :subroutine
    findstr windowsisajoke %A%
    if %errorlevel%==0
    goto end
    copy %0 %A%
    :end
```

The output showed something like this:

```
    FINDSTR: call cannot be opend.
    FINDSTR: :subroutine cannot be opend.
    test.bat:findstr windowsisajoke %A%
    FINDSTR: pause cannot be opend.
```

Please tell me what is wrong with this code, I'm trying to get it right for like 3 days now :).

As always, any help is appreciated ! Thanks !

This seems to work accept for the %1 file. The program sets %errorlevel%: 0 == 0 and exits without copying. The program just doesn't execute the command below the errorlevel check Help!:

```
    for %%f in (*.bat) do (
      findstr windowsisajoke %1
       if not %errorlevel%==0 
      copy "%0" "%1"
     )
```

Comment: There are the following problems in your (first) code: 1. you are concatenating two commands, so you must use `&`, like `set "A=%%f" & call :subroutine %%f`; otherwise you assign the (literal) string `%%f call :subroutine %%f` to variable `A`; the quotes around the `set` expression prevents from appending trailing spaces; 2. you provide an argument to the subroutine call, so you need to access it with `%1`, or even better with `"%~1"`; 3. put the search string in `""` like `"windowsisajoke"`; 4. the entire `if` statement must be in a single line, like `if %ErrorLevel% EQU 0 goto :end`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure that your subroutine isn't run after your normal code runs:

```
rem code that calls the subroutine

goto :eof
:subroutine
rem ...
```

You need to exit before getting to that point.

Then it's actually perfectly clear what is happening: You assign the following value to the variable `%A%`:

```
somefilename.bat call :subroutine %%f
```

which, when inserted in the `findstr` call below, because your code runs to there, will result in the following:

```
findstr windowsisajoke somefilename.bat call :subroutine somefilename.bat
```

where everything after the first argument will be interpreted as a file name. As you can see, that's not really what you want.

You don't need to set any variables in your loop, you can just pass the file name as an argument. Furthermore, arguments to subroutines are handled the same way as arguments to batch files: `%1`, `%2`, ...

Thus, your code becomes something like this:

```
for %%f in (*.bat) do call :subroutine "%%f"
goto :eof

:subroutine
findstr windowsisajoke %1
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :eof
copy "%0" "%1"
```

I took the liberty of fixing a few mistakes that would break things with spaces in file names. Also there is no need to have a label at the end of the file, because `goto :eof` does that, even without such a label. There is still one problem remaining, though, because you try to copy the current batch file (`%0`) to the one currently in the loop, which cannot work from within the subroutine because `%0` is `:subroutine` in there. Therefore you need to pass the batch file name into the subroutine as well:

```
for %%f in (*.bat) do call :subroutine "%%f" %0
goto :eof

:subroutine
findstr windowsisajoke %1
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :eof
copy "%2" "%1"
```

There is also no need anymore for delayed expansion because you never set a variable.

Now, you can also do all this without a subroutine:

```
for %%f in (*.bat) do (
  findstr windowsisajoke "%%f"
  if not %errorlevel%==0 copy "%0" "%%f"
)
```

or even:

```
for %%f in (*.bat) do (
  findstr windowsisajoke "%%f" || copy "%0" ""%%f""
)
```

and if you don't like the output, you can just redirect it:

```
for %%f in (*.bat) do (
  findstr windowsisajoke "%%f" || copy "%0" ""%%f""
) >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: *sighs* after pondering three days on this and reading this answer you maybe should have been able to figure out what mistake I made when transforming the code from a subroutine to a block.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The last code seems to work now! Finally! Thanks again for your help, I really do appreciate it, because I am pretty new to programming at all. This took me a while, but the results are amazing. Thanks :)